# Explanation of verse 24:62

Tags: quran, hadith, tafseer, prophet-muhammad

> The believers are only those who believe in Allah and His Messenger
> and, when they are [meeting] with him for a matter of common interest,
> do not depart until they have asked his permission. **Indeed, those
> who ask your permission, [O Muhammad] – those are the ones who believe
> in Allah and His Messenger**. So when they ask your permission due to
> something of their affairs, then give permission to whom you will
> among them and ask forgiveness for them of Allah. Indeed, Allah is
> Forgiving and Merciful. ([24] An-Nur : 62)

It says here that those who ask permission to leave are believers. But we know that the hypocrites also asked the Prophet for permission to stay at home during the jihad:

> Allah has pardoned you, why did you give them
> permission [to remain behind]? [You should not have] until it was
> evident to you who were truthful and you knew [who were] the liars.
> ([9] At-Tawbah : 43)

Maybe I didn't understand something in this verse 24:62, so I turn to the knowledgeable for clarification.
Does this verse mean that every person who asked permission from the Prophet was a believer? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

The permission in the first verse is only limited to "when they are [meeting] with him for a matter of common interest".

But the permission in the second verse is to remain behind the Prophet S.A. and refrain from participating in the war against the enemies of Islam in his company.

So, there is no conflict between these two verses.

Comment: I gave the second verse as an example. I want to say that if a hypocrite asks permission from the Prophet, he will not become a believer. So why does the verse say that: the one who asks permission = the believer.

Comment: @Insan this verse has 3 terms for a believer. not only one you said. the 3 should be true together. only one is not enough. There is "AND" between terms. not OR. a hypocrite has not still believed in Allah and His Messenger